# Make background as tall as the tallest child element

Tags: css, ckeditor, background-color, font-size

We have [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) on our site, and *font size* and *background color* buttons don't play together very well.

Suppose we have this text:

```
Foo Bar Baz
```

When the user applies background color to the whole text, and then applies bigger font size to "Bar", this HTML is generated ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvbLt832/)):

```
<span style="background-color: yellow">
    Foo
    <span style="font-size: 30px">
        Bar
    </span>
    Baz
</span>
```

This results in "Bar" not being fully covered by background:

[image]

I "fixed" it by adding `display: inline-block` to the outer `span` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/or84odxn/)):

```
<span style="background-color: yellow; display: inline-block">
    Foo
    <span style="font-size: 30px">
        Bar
    </span>
    Baz
</span>
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this change broke highlighting with background color in other cases.

With `display: inline-block` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovg2oga4/)):

[image]

Without ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkk1nb3m/)):

[image]

With `display: inline-block` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3opbx6op/)):

[image]

Without ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3opbx6op/2/)):

[image]

So, my question is, how can I fix the background of the larger text without using `display: inline-block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case you need to add
background-color: yellow;
to the inner .

It's not make the line in same height.
But, it's seems to be the most logical way to solve this issue.
Because you don't want to make all the line in same height.

Comment: Thanks! I added this CSS: `.outer-span * { background-color: inherit }` and now it works like a charm.